# How to approximate a function in the H-model

Tags: equities, valuation, discounting

I have been looking to understand the H-model in finance, that is used for stock price valuation. In particular, I wanted to formally derive the final formula:

$$PV=\frac{D}{r-g_2}\left[1+g_2+\frac{H}{2}(g_1-g_2)\right]$$

Here $PV>0$ is the present value (price) of the stock, $D>0$ is the constant dividend payment that is paid forever, $r\in(0;1)$ is the required rate of return on the stock and the growth rate of the stock follows a pattern: it starts with a growth rate of $g_1\in(0;1)$ and at time $H\ge0$ the growth rate switches to $g_2<g_1$, $g_2\in(0;1)$. When $H=0$ the model is equivalent to the Gordon growth model, where we simply evaluate a perpetuity (perpetual stream of discounted and growing dividends). In general the present value should be

$$PV=D\frac{1+g_1}{1+r}+D\left(\frac{1+g_1}{1+r}\right)^2+...+D\left(\frac{1+g_1}{1+r}\right)^{H-1}+D\left(\frac{1+g_1}{1+r}\right)^{H}+D\frac{(1+g_1)^{H}(1+g_2)}{(1+r)^{H+1}}+D\frac{(1+g_1)^{H}(1+g_2)^2}{(1+r)^{H+2}}+...=D\sum_{i=1}^{H}{\left(\frac{1+g_1}{1+r}\right)^i}+{D\left(\frac{1+g_1}{1+g_2}\right)^{H}\sum_{i=H+1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1+g_2}{1+r}\right)^i}}$$
I evaluated it to be
$$PV=D\frac{1+g_1}{r-g_1}\left(1-\left(\frac{1+g_1}{1+r}\right)^{H-1}\cdot\frac{g_1-g_2}{r-g_2}\right)$$
The paper I found on https://wenku.baidu.com/view/07ef434ae45c3b3567ec8b84.html agrees with me, and it states that the expression I computed can be approximated using the formula of the H-model I showed at the beginning, but does not give a derivation. The paper only gives a strange footnote 'The formal derivation of the H-model ... is available from the authors', but no further elaboration is given. I would be glad to receive any hints as to what technique one should use in order to arrive at the final result